# How to connect two LED strips (APA102/SK9822) to Arduino UNO?

Tags: arduino-uno, spi, rgb-led, led-strip

So what I am trying to do is to connect two SK9822 LED strips to Arduino UNO.

I am a bit confused about how to properly set this up so I can individualy control any led. So obviously 5V should go to 5V and GND to GND, but what about the CLOCK and the DATA pin.

According to the tutorials and stuff I found here, CLOCK pin needs to be connected to pin 13 and DATA to pin 10, but they only use one strip... so what I am trying to ask is can LED strips share pins? Can they be connected to the same CLOCK pin and different DATA pins or how can i set this up to use the minimum amount of pins?

I was planning on using FastLED library, where it looks like you can specify which pin is DATA and which is CLOCK,

```
FastLED.addLeds<APA102, DATA_PIN, CLOCK_PIN>(leds, NUM_LEDS);
```

Is this because different boards have different CLK and MOSI pins or can i use any pin and set it as CLOCK or DATA? This is probably obvious but I am new to this and this is my first project.

Comment: Did you give it a try? This [FastLED Wiki page](https://github.com/FastLED/FastLED/wiki/SPI-Hardware-or-Bit-banging) gives you some suggestions for Arduino connectivity. Tip: An Arduino Uno uses the 328P MCU. But the wiki page implies that any(?) pins can be used by FastLED. If h/w SPI support is available on the pins it will use it automatically (implying that if h/w support is not available, it will drive them via s/w).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about SK9822 LED strips, however the other type of led strips can be used with every pin; this is to support multiple LED strips.

Because every LED strip has its own CLK input (wire), it would be inconvenient to share them... I'm not sure if it is possible practically, because the timing is critical and if you have just one 'master' CLK signal than the data signals for all LED strips should be sent in time. Also writing the library would be more difficult, since there is a relation between a (shared) CLK signal and other data lines.

Answer (score 1):

For minimum pins, daisychain them together, with the clock and data outputs on the tail end of the first strip connecting to the clock and data inputs on the second strip.

https://www.pololu.com/product/3089 says:

> Multiple LED strips can be chained together by connecting input
> connectors to output connectors. When strips are chained this way,
> they can be controlled and powered as one continuous strip.